# mostrar un mensaje de error o bloquear si la hora y la fecha del computador no es correcta php

Tags: php, javascript

necesito hacer con php una comprobacion de la hora, una que me muestre un mensaje de error si la hora de la computadora es menor a la del servidor que muestre un mensaje de alerta, hasta ahora con mucha ayuda consegui traer las 2 fechas pero , los valores de las 2 como tal no son remotamente cerca

hagp la prueba y la hora convertida en entero en javascript me arroja

1533156284660

y la hora en php me arroja

998122565

index.php

```
   <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var f=new Date();
var hora=f.getTime(); 
$.post("hora.php",{hora:hora},function(d){alert(d)});
</script>
```

hora.php

```
<?php
//configuro la zona horario de mi server 
date_default_timezone_set('America/Manaus');
//tomo la hora del servidor
$hora = strtotime(date('d-m-y h:i:s'));
// esto es un if corto y comparo el post que mande de index con la hora del servidor
$hora == $_POST['hora'] ? $res = "Es igual" : $res = "No es igual";
echo $_POST["hora"]." - ".$hora;
?>
```

Comment: php te mostrara la hora del servidor solamente para saber la hora de algún cliente tendrás que mandársela por JS

Comment: gracias @JoseLuisEsparza puedes decirme como es eso de "mandarsela"

Comment: [](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/May%C3%BAscula).

Answer (score 2):

puedes intentar lo siguiente

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    //obtiene fecha del ordenador local
    var f=new Date();
    //obtiene solo la hora y minutos poniendo los ceros a la izquierda
    var hora=('0' + f.getHours()).slice(-2)+":"+('0'+f.getMinutes()).slice(-2); 
    //manda el post a la pagina hora.php con la informacion de la hora
    $.post("hora.php",{hora:hora},function(d){alert(d)});
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**hora.php**

```
<?php
//configuro la zona horario en mi caso es chihuahua
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chihuahua');
//tomo la hora del servidor
$hora = date('H:i');
// esto es un if corto y comparo el post que mande de index con la hora del servidor
$hora == $_POST['hora'] ? $res = "Es igual" : $res = "No es igual";
echo $res;
```

Comment: ¿puedes explicarme tu código? siempre me aparece que no es igual .

Comment: estoy usando el jquery 
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: voy a editar la pregunta, queda mucho por aclarar

Comment: he modificado el ejemplo con unas correcciones por lo que te pudo hace que saliera siempre diferente el if

Comment: creo que se acerca a lo que busco hacer , pero lo que no entiendo es si yo solo comparo la hora por ejemplo , haciendolo de esta manera

Comment: por que no me aparece "Es igual" si solo estoy comparando la hora ? 
$hora = date('H');

Comment: imprime las oras en ves del $res, pon echo $_POST["hora"]." - ".$hora; y checa que esta devolviendo los dos

Comment: 13:00 - 10 esto es lo que sale

Comment: eso quiere decir que en tu computadora es la una o 13:00 hrs y en la del servidor tienes configurada una zona horaria que no corresponde a donde estas tu y marca las 10

Comment: gracias, todo me quedo mas claro ahora, si , era la zona de Chihuahua , yo uso manaus , cuando cambie la hora pude ver el resultado esperado, tengo una ultima duda macho, como le puedo quitar media hora o agregarsela a los 2 codigos php y javascript?

Comment: como podria hacer para confirmar la fecha.bro, si u usuario cambia la hora y la fecha puede ver la info que precisamente me gustaria bloquear

Comment: quieres bloquear la configuración de fecha y hora de los usuarios?

Comment: si, necesito que si ellos cambian eso pueda mostrar un mensaje de error

Comment: voy a editar la pregunta, con tu ayuda he avanzado pero no entiendo ahora por que pasa lo de la imagen...